# Export a map and a legend as a PNG with OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, legend, mapping, png

I would like to export a map with a legend in the same PNG using OpenLayers 6. I searched in the OpenLayers documentation but I got just  how to export a map  (without a legend). How can I do this?

Comment: dom-to-image-more (or html-to-image, they are almost identical) has a toPng method, see this version 6.0.0 example https://openlayers.org/en/v6.0.0/examples/export-map.html

Comment: thank you soooo much , it's working now

Comment: Could one of you please add this as an answer (perhaps with a little more detail) and then mark it as answered?

Comment: sorry , but i don't know how to mark it as answered !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the code, maybe it's will help someone:

```
  var exportOptions = {
  filter: function(element) {
    var className = element.className || '';
    return (
      className.indexOf('ol-control') === -1 ||
      className.indexOf('ol-legend') > -1 ||
      (className.indexOf('ol-attribution') > -1 &&
        className.indexOf('ol-uncollapsible'))
    );
  },
};

document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener(
  'click', function() {
  map.once('rendercomplete', function() {
    domtoimage
    .toJpeg(map.getTargetElement(), exportOptions)
      .then(function(dataURL) {
        var link = document.getElementById('image-download');
        link.href = dataURL;
        link.click();
      });
  });
  map.renderSync();
});
```